# Then why os can't the content be read directly into the user buffer?

Tags: linux, operating-system

When the operating system reads the content of the file, it first reads the content into the kernel buffer, and then copies it into the user buffer. Why can't the read data be directly stored in the user buffer? Doesn't this reduce a memory copy?

I hope someone can give a more detailed explanation

Comment: please see O_DIRECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some reasons:

1. The device that the data resides on (disc) may require specific alignment in order to perform i/o.
2. The device may only deliver i/o in sizes larger than the user provided.
3. The user request might comprise several disc sectors, and the beginning and end may not align to device requirements.
4. The user buffer may be inappropriate for DMA because of constraints such as the above, or a system may have other DMA constraints.

In general, you can achieve zero copy i/o via mmap().   In that scenario the system can align and choose the mapped buffer area to conform to alignment and address constraints of the target hardware.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation.  .